# Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react component, its a very simple example to start to learn react , and  I get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`, I¡, not sure what it's wrong

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=ç, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="./mynumber.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mynumber.js

```
import React from 'react';

class MyNumber extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div>Hello</div>
    }
}

export default MyNumber
```

and index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyNumber from './mynumber';


const container = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render( MyNumber,container);
```

Comment: React projects are usually bundled up via [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), which produces a single js file with all of your imports resolved. I don't think you can just include each file in your page via a script tag and expect imports to work. If you want to get started with React without getting into all of the setup headaches, you can create an instant project on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) using their react template, or you can run `npx create-react-app MyAppName`.

Comment: I see this line ```ReactDOM.render( MyNumber,container);``` should be ```ReactDOM.render( <MyNumber />,container);```